# How can I make the DNS server list persist on OS X?

Tags: networking, macos, dns

I usually set the DNS servers on my laptop to be `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`, which are Google's DNS servers, via the System Preferences > Network > $Interface > DNS pane.

Far too often though, these servers reset to the ones broadcasted by my home gateway -- not just on reboot or when bringing an interface down and back up, sometimes seemingly at random.

I can see these changes, again, in the System Preferences > Network > $Interface > DNS pane.

Is there a way to make my DNS settings persistent?

Comment: Please edit your question to say how/where you were setting them (Network pref pane of System Preferences? Hand editing `/etc/resolv.conf`?), how/where you saw that they'd been reset, and what they got reset to (e.g. "they got reset to the DNS addresses my home gateway gives out via DHCP", "they got reset to the previous manually entered DNS addresses")

Comment: @Spiff updated.

Answer (score 1):

These settings *are* persistent, but they're set per "Location". Also, the GUI hierarchy can give the misleading impression of them being per-interface, but there's really just one set of DNS servers which applies to all interfaces.

So if you've been switching "Locations" or editing "other interfaces' DNS settings", you've accidentally been changing it yourself.

It's also possible that another process on your system is changing the System Configuration database behind your back. I'd look at what VPN or security software you have installed. Maybe your corporate VPN software is trying to make sure your DNS queries go to the internal DNS server so you can resolve internal-scope host names. Maybe it's not restoring your preference when the VPN tunnel goes down unexpectedly.

Answer (score -1):

From my own experience, if you have a DHCP-assigned IP Address, Gateway, and Router, then the DNS will automatically set itself as well. If you change the DNS manually, it will stick, but likely only until the DHCP lease expire and renews. Google's DNS will be forgotten in favor of whatever you ISP wants.

Try setting a completely manual address, and DNS, and see what happens.

Comment: This is not true of macOS.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm writing this from a Mac Air, and that has been my experience so far.